# Apache DocumentRoot doesn't change

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, arch-linux

I'm trying to set up an Apache 2 server on my Arch Linux machine. Everything works great so far, including https and php, but now I want to change the `DocumentRoot` from the default `/srv/http` to `/var/www/foo`. I changed `DocumentRoot /srv/http` and `<Directory "/srv/http">` to `DocumentRoot /var/www/foo` and `<Directory "/var/www/foo">` respectively and reloaded the configuration using `systemctl restart httpd`. Now I'm getting 403 errors when trying to access `https://localhost` or anything within.

Further investigation turns out that changing the `<Directory ...>` declaration has an effect, but changing the `DocumentRoot` doesn't. When I set `Require all granted` in `<Directory />` to eliminate these 403 errors, it turns out Apache is still trying to serve documents from `/srv/http`. For instance, I put a test.php file containing `<?php echo exec('pwd'); ?>` into both `/srv/http/` and `/var/www/foo/` and accessing `https://localhost/test.php` outputs `/srv/http` to my browser. Trying to access documents located in `/var/www/foo` but not in `/srv/http` will result in 404 errors.

Why is Apache still using `/srv/http`? I changed absolutely every occurence of `/srv/http` to `/var/www/foo` in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` and restarted Apache several times, but my document root just won't change. According to the Apache Arch Wiki article, I've done everything that's necessairy.

I could of course just symlink `/srv/http` to the desired location, but that doesn't seem like the proper way to go.

Here are the parts of my `httpd.config` that I think might be relevant:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted     # Will of course change to denied again once everything works
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/foo"

<Directory "/var/www/foo">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Of course, `/var/www/foo` itself and all parent directories have at least `755` permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any [VirtualHost](http://support.moonpoint.com/blog/blosxom/2009/04/17#default-virtualhost) sections in `httpd.conf`? If you have a `VirtualHost` section with `/srv/http` set as its `DocumentRoot`, it is possible Apache is using that directory from the `VirtualHost` section, even though you have changed the `DocumentRoot` value outside of the `VirtualHost` section.

Comment: No, I don't have any virtual host set up. Besides, that wouldn't make a difference because I used vim's search feature to make sure there is no occurence of `/srv/http` left.

Comment: Though the problem you encountered may be unrelated to a VirtualHost setting, Apache can also load virtual hosts from an external file, e.g. `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` - see [How To Set Up Apache Virtual Hosts on Arch Linux](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-arch-linux) - so you could check to see whether that line exists and is or is not commented out in `httpd.conf`. If it isn't commented out, you could put a `#` at the beginning of the line to make it a comment and restart Apache to see whether that makes a difference.

Comment: @Raptilicus, you could also check the main error log to see if there is anything unusual there that might offer a clue to the problem. The location for that file is shown if you run `apachectl -S`. That also shows the default value for `DocumentRoot`, but the value you see for `DocumentRoot` there is not necessarily the one used for `localhost` if a `VirtualHost` section is in effect either within `httpd.conf` or from an external `httpd-vhosts.conf` file.

Comment: The `vhosts.conf` was not included. But investigating further in that direction, I found out that `httpd-ssl.conf` contained such a virtual host setup explicitly using `/srv/http`. I changed that to `/var/www/foo`, too, and now everything works! Thanks!